# Armature with automatic weights is deforming mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, parent

I have created a pretty standard armature but when I try and apply it to my mesh it deforms it pretty wildly. I have removed doubles, but nothing changed. I think areas with higher poly counts are attaching to the armature but I'm not sure. https://youtu.be/_UcUPfmRt-0

Comment: Apply scales and rotations before parenting. Ctrl+A.

Comment: I applied scales and rotation but nothing changed?

Comment: Could you upload your file so that we can have a look? Please use this link to do it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6gmwqj1d" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6gmwqj1d/)\ Here you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesh normals are inverted which is the main cause of the issue.

[image]

To correct it, enter edit mode, select all and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

Also the mesh is scaled and rotated. Preferably, apply scales and rotations before parenting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in object mode.

Last point, the armature is not in rest position: set it to it or set the current pose as rest pose.

[image]